# Understanding difference between following javascript notations

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn js codes and was going through some sample codes at GitHub and was confused between these codes. What is the difference between following or they are same.I deleted the contents inside to keep it simple.

```
on_success: (file_doc) => {
}


on_success(file_doc) {
}
```

Comment: They're both invalid syntax without a context. And context matters. It will show you what the difference is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first notation can be used only **in object literals**, and assigns an anonymous **arrow function** to the object's property `on_success`. In contrast to a non-arrow function, this preserves the outer `this`; so `this` inside the function will point to whatever it pointed to at the moment of assignment.

Example:

```
const obj = {
  on_success: (file_doc) => {},
}

obj.on_success();
```

The second notation can only be used **in Javascript classes**, and defines a named non-arrow-function on each instance of the class. Non-arrow (also known as *ES5-function*) means `this` inside it will reference whatever the execution context of the function is.

Example:

```
class Foo {
  on_success(file_doc) {}
}

const bar = new Foo;
bar.on_success();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's same as:

```js
const success = (file_doc) => {

}

function success(file_doc) {

}
```

The first one called **arrow syntax function** or method introduced in ES6 and the second one is from ES5 (correct me if I'm wrong)

They're the same as a function or method but the arrow syntax function doesn't have **this** and **arguments** variable.